# Vue3 App operating differently in alternate environments

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to deploy an app, hosted on Firebase. I have two instances running to demonstrate the problem. It's a questionnaire using vue-flow-form.

For normal operation, once a user types in the answer box, then a continue button appears or they can hit enter to move to the next question. This is working fine on the URL below.

For the problem area, 'false' appears in the question box and no button appears - so users cannot progress.

Both environments have identical code for the Questionnaire.vue, but in the 'problem area' the vue file sits amongst a Userfront stack.

Problem area: https://auth-32463.web.app/
Working fine area: https://vuetest29aug.web.app/

The code is identical (minus the welcome message). I'm getting no errors on build/serve/deploy.

Questionnaire.vue code

```js
// Create and setup your form here
 // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "o",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
<template>
    <div>
        <header class="vff-header">
            <div class="f-container">
                <!-- Add custom logo here -->
                <svg class="f-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 35.606 11.211">
                    <path d="M.134.837H3.21V8.01h4.203v2.18H.134V.837z" />
                    <path d="M11.875.59c1.48 0 2.668.448 3.567 1.344s1.35 2.052 1.35 3.47c0 1.48-.445 2.7-1.336 3.632S13.38 10.45 11.9 10.45c-1.678 0-2.954-.54-3.827-1.622-.717-.9-1.08-2.022-1.09-3.397-.01-1.36.39-2.484 1.193-3.374C9.06 1.08 10.292.59 11.875.59zm0 2.283c-.563 0-1.003.222-1.323.662-.338.467-.507 1.124-.507 1.972 0 .865.162 1.524.487 1.978a1.58 1.58 0 0 0 1.369.682c.588 0 1.04-.223 1.355-.668s.474-1.07.474-1.875c0-1.834-.62-2.75-1.855-2.75z" />
                    <path d="M21.565 7.078V5.055h4.217v5.163h-1.986l-.13-.908c-.693.76-1.617 1.142-2.777 1.142-1.383 0-2.488-.437-3.313-1.3s-1.243-2.03-1.252-3.464c-.01-1.462.385-2.65 1.18-3.567.875-1.012 2.11-1.518 3.7-1.518 1.21 0 2.207.303 3 .907s1.264 1.457 1.447 2.556h-2.92c-.207-.787-.73-1.182-1.57-1.182-.553 0-.988.236-1.303.707s-.475 1.153-.475 2.043c0 1.695.652 2.542 1.96 2.542.363 0 .695-.103.998-.306a1.29 1.29 0 0 0 .572-.784h-1.35v.002z" />
                    <path d="M30.556.59c1.48 0 2.668.448 3.568 1.344s1.348 2.052 1.348 3.47c0 1.48-.443 2.7-1.336 3.632S32.06 10.45 30.58 10.45c-1.678 0-2.953-.54-3.826-1.622-.72-.892-1.082-2.022-1.1-3.398-.008-1.357.39-2.48 1.193-3.372C27.74 1.08 28.974.59 30.556.59zm0 2.283c-.563 0-1.002.222-1.322.662-.336.467-.506 1.125-.506 1.972 0 .865.162 1.524.486 1.978s.78.682 1.37.682 1.04-.223 1.355-.668.475-1.07.475-1.875c-.002-1.834-.62-2.75-1.857-2.75z" />
                </svg>
            </div>
        </header>

        <flow-form ref="flowform"
                   v-on:complete="onComplete"
                   v-on:submit="onSubmit"
                   v-bind:questions="questions"
                   v-bind:language="language"
                   v-bind:standalone="true">
            <!-- Custom content for the Complete/Submit screen slots in the FlowForm component -->
            <!-- We've overriden the default "complete" slot content -->
            <template v-slot:complete>
                <div class="f-section-wrap">
                    <p>
                        <span class="fh2">Thank you. </span>
                        <span class="f-section-text">
                            Great work, the survey is completed, and our mint is done. You can review your answers or press submit.
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="f-description">Note: No data will be saved and/or sent in this demo.</p>
                </div>
            </template>

            <!-- We've overriden the default "completeButton" slot content -->
            <template v-slot:completeButton>
                <div class="f-submit" v-if="!submitted">
                    <button class="o-btn-action"
                            ref="button"
                            type="submit"
                            href="#"
                            v-on:click="onSendData('test1')"
                            aria-label="Press to submit">
                        <span>{{ language.submitText }}</span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="f-enter-desc"
                       href="#"
                       v-on:click="onSendData('test2')"
                       v-html="language.formatString(language.pressEnter)">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <p class="text-success" v-if="submitted">Submitted succesfully.</p>
            </template>
        </flow-form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    /*
      Copyright (c) 2020 - present, DITDOT Ltd. - MIT Licence
      https://www.ditdot.hr/en
    */

    // Import necessary components and classes
    import FlowForm from '../../src/components/FlowForm.vue'
    import QuestionModel, { QuestionType, ChoiceOption, LinkOption } from '../../src/models/QuestionModel'
    import LanguageModel from '../../src/models/LanguageModel'
    // If using the npm package, use the following line instead of the ones above.
    // import FlowForm, { QuestionModel, QuestionType, ChoiceOption, LanguageModel } from '@ditdot-dev/vue-flow-form'

    export default {
        name: 'example',

        components: {
            FlowForm
        },

        data() {
            return {
                submitted: false,
                completed: false,
                language: new LanguageModel(),
                // Create question list with QuestionModel instances
                questions: [
                    new QuestionModel({
                        id: 'first_name',
                        tagline: 'V1 demo survey ',
                        title: 'What is your first name?',
                        type: QuestionType.Text,
                        required: true,
                        placeholder: 'Start typing here...'
                    }),
                    new QuestionModel({
                        id: 'email',
                        name: 'email',
                        tagline: "Nice to meet you , let's continue",
                        title: 'Provide an example email.',
                        type: QuestionType.Email,
                        required: true,
                        placeholder: 'Start typing here...'
                    }),
                    /*new QuestionModel({
                      id: 'multiple_choice_image',
                      tagline: "Let's take it one step further...",
                      title: 'Tell us what is your favorite social network hangout.',
                      helpTextShow: false,
                      type: QuestionType.MultiplePictureChoice,
                      multiple: true,
                      required: true,
                      options: [
                        new ChoiceOption({
                          imageSrc: require('./assets/images/facebook.png'),
                          imageAlt: 'Facebook logo',
                          label: 'Facebook'
                        }),
                        new ChoiceOption({
                          imageSrc: require('./assets/images/twitter.png'),
                          imageAlt: 'Twitter logo',
                          label: 'Twitter'
                        }),
                        new ChoiceOption({
                          imageSrc: require('./assets/images/instagram.png'),
                          imageAlt: 'Instagram logo',
                          label: 'Instagram'
                        }),
                        new ChoiceOption({
                          imageSrc: require('./assets/images/tiktok.png'),
                          imageAlt: 'TikTok logo',
                          label: 'TikTok'
                        }),
                      ]
                    }),
                    new QuestionModel({
                      id: 'phone',
                      title: 'Doing great!  Go ahead and try with a phone number.',
                      type: QuestionType.Phone,
                      required: true,
                      mask: '(###) ###-####'
                    }),
                    new QuestionModel({
                      id: 'movies',
                      title: 'List your favorite movies. ',
                      type: QuestionType.LongText,
                      required: true,
                      placeholder: 'Start typing here...'
                    }),
                    new QuestionModel({
                      id: 'icon_rate',
                      tagline: "Thanks for that. Now, let's give it some ⭐ rating",
                      title: 'How good was the last movie you watched?',
                      type: QuestionType.IconRate,
                      required: true,
                      max: 5
                    }),
                    new QuestionModel({
                      id: 'opinion_scale',
                      title: 'Choose a number to express your opinion ',
                      subtitle: 'You can also use ⌨️ numbers to select an option',
                      type: QuestionType.OpinionScale,
                      required: true,
                      max: 5,
                      labelLeft: 'Dissapointing',
                      labelRight: 'Exceptional'
                    }),
                    new QuestionModel({
                      id: 'multiple_choice',
                      tagline: 'FYI, You can always go back , use the up arrow on the bottom.',
                      title: 'Multiple choice question:',
                      helpTextShow: false,
                      type: QuestionType.MultipleChoice,
                      multiple: false,
                      allowOther: true,
                      required: true,
                      options: [
                        new ChoiceOption({
                          label: 'Answer 1'
                        }),
                        new ChoiceOption({
                          label: 'Answer 2'
                         }),
                        new ChoiceOption({
                          label: 'Answer 3'
                        })
                      ]
                    }),
                    new QuestionModel({
                      id: 'multiple_choices',
                      title: 'Multiple choices question:',
                      type: QuestionType.MultipleChoice,
                      multiple: true,
                      helpText: 'Select all that apply. ',
                      required: true,
                      options: [
                        new ChoiceOption({
                          label: 'Answer 1'
                        }),
                        new ChoiceOption({
                          label: 'Answer 2'
                        }),
                        new ChoiceOption({
                          label: 'Answer 3'
                        }),
                        new ChoiceOption({
                          label: 'Answer 4'
                        })
                      ]
                    }),

                    new QuestionModel({
                      id: 'break_1',
                      title: 'Awesome, thank you. ',
                      content: 'You arrived at the section break of our little demo survey. To continue exploring, just press enter or use the continue button.',
                      description: 'Note: We will take a look at our multiple path feature next.',
                      type: QuestionType.SectionBreak
                    }),
                    new QuestionModel({
                      id: 'choose_path',
                      tagline: 'Where would you like to go? ',
                      title: 'Choose your path:',
                      type: QuestionType.Dropdown,
                      multiple: false,
                      placeholder: 'Select',
                      inline: true,
                      required: true,
                      options: [
                        new ChoiceOption({
                          label: 'Path A'
                        }),
                        new ChoiceOption({
                          label: 'Path B',
                          value: 'path_b'
                        })
                      ],
                      jump: {
                        path_b: 'path_b'
                      }
                    }),*/
                    new QuestionModel({
                        id: 'path_a',
                        title: 'Excellent choice! ',
                        content: 'Press enter or use the continue button for the final submit screen.',
                        type: QuestionType.SectionBreak,
                        jump: {
                            _other: '_submit'
                        }
                    }),
                    new QuestionModel({
                        id: 'path_b',
                        tagline: 'Path B',
                        title: 'Hmm, are you sure?',
                        helpText: 'Path A sounds like a winner! ',
                        type: QuestionType.MultipleChoice,
                        multiple: false,
                        required: true,
                        options: [
                            new ChoiceOption({
                                label: 'Ok, let\'s go with A',
                                value: 'path_a'
                            }),
                            new ChoiceOption({
                                label: 'Yes, finish the survey'
                            })
                        ],
                        jump: {
                            path_a: 'path_a'
                        }
                    })
                ]
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            document.addEventListener('keyup', this.onKeyListener)
        },

        beforeUnmount() {
            document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.onKeyListener)
        },

        methods: {
            onKeyListener($event) {
                // We've overriden the default "complete" slot so
                // we need to implement the "keyup" listener manually.

                if ($event.key === 'Enter' && this.completed && !this.submitted) {
                    this.onSendData('test3')
                }
            },

            /* eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars */
            onComplete(completed, questionList) {
                // This method is called whenever the "completed" status is changed.
                this.completed = completed
            },

            /* eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars */
            onSubmit(questionList) {
                // This method will only be called if you don't override the
                // completeButton slot.

                const temparray = []

                questionList.forEach(question => {
                    temparray.push(question.answer)
                })

                this.onSendData(temparray)
            },

            onSendData(QuestionsArray) {
                // Set `submitted` to true so the form knows not to allow back/forward
                // navigation anymore.

                this.$refs.flowform.submitted = true

                this.submitted = true

                /* eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars */
                const data = this.getData()
                //console.log(email)

                fetch('hidden/test.json', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        Q1: QuestionsArray[0],
                        Q2: QuestionsArray[1],
                        Q3: QuestionsArray[2],
                        Q4: QuestionsArray[3],
                        Q5: QuestionsArray[4],
                        Q6: QuestionsArray[5],
                        Q7: QuestionsArray[6],
                        Q8: QuestionsArray[7],
                        Q9: QuestionsArray[8],
                        Q10: QuestionsArray[9]

                    })
                });
            },

            getData() {
                const data = {
                    questions: [],
                    answers: []
                }

                this.questions.forEach(question => {
                    if (question.title) {
                        let answer = question.answer
                        if (Array.isArray(answer)) {
                            answer = answer.join(', ')
                        }

                        data.questions.push(question.title)
                        data.answers.push(answer)
                    }
                })

                return data
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="css">
    @import '../../src/assets/css/themes/theme-minimal.css';
    /* If using the npm package, use the following lines instead of the one above */
    /* @import '~@ditdot-dev/vue-flow-form/dist/vue-flow-form.css'; */
    /* @import '~@ditdot-dev/vue-flow-form/dist/vue-flow-form.theme-minimal.css'; */
</style>
```

Comment: In the first link https://auth-32463.web.app/questionnaire is unavailable for guests. It's unclear what is the problem and how it's reproduced

Comment: Sorry @EstusFlask - that restriction is disabled now.